# How to transform cartesian coordinate system to polar coordinate system in WPF?

Tags: wpf, coordinates, transform

I need to transforming cartesian coordinate system to polar coordinate system in WPF. I want to transform linear object to circle. How I can do it?

Comment: What kind of object do you want to use for these transformation?

Comment: Transformable object is any WPF object, what inherited from FrameworkElement. Element what do transform may be any, but WPF used for transformation Transform class.